# Typoscript join

Tags: join, typo3, typoscript

I need to select * from tt_content where colPos=4 and uid is in sys_category_record_mm (category Uid_local=14)

I try this, but result was null

```
styles.content.getTop {
    table= tt_content
    select{
        selectFields = *
        join = sys_category_record_mm ON (sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign=tt_content.uid)
        where = tt_content.colPos=4
        andWhere = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local=14

    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Configure sqlDebug in your install tool display all queries, then find the query generated and you should know more about your problem.

Comment: Thanx lorenz

The problem was missing orderBy

    styles.content.getTop {
     table = tt_content
     select{
      orderBy = tt_content.sorting
      selectFields = *
      join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign=tt_content.uid
      where = tt_content.colPos=4
      andWhere = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local=14
    
     }
    }

I think default is "sorting" but if 2 tables are joined sorting is ambiguous so i must add tt_content.sorting

:-)

Comment: Please set the question to solved if it is. Great it worked out!

Comment: Hi Lorenz, I don't now, how I can set this answer to solved... :-(

Comment: Click the check icon at the left of your answer. Then you can close it as "community wiki".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx lorenz

The problem was missing orderBy

```
styles.content.getTop {
    table = tt_content
    select{
        orderBy = tt_content.sorting
        selectFields = *
        join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign=tt_content.uid
        where = tt_content.colPos=4
        andWhere = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local=14

    }
}
```

I think default is "sorting" but if 2 tables are joined sorting is ambiguous so i must add tt_content.sorting

:-)